# What's wrong with this usage of IPC::Open3?

Tags: perl

```
use IPC::Open3;

local(*A, *B, *C);

my $cmd = \&run;
my @args = ();
my $childpid = open3(*A, *B, *C, $cmd, @args);
print A "stuff\n";
close(A); 
my @outlines = <B>; 
my @errlines = <C>; 
print "STDOUT:\n", @outlines, "\n";
print "STDERR:\n", @errlines, "\n";
close B;
close C;
waitpid($childpid, 0);
if ($?) {
    print "That child exited with wait status of $?\n";
}

sub run {

}
```

It's reporting:

```
STDERR:
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `0x67bc50'
sh: -c: line 0: `CODE(0x67bc50)'
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `$cmd` should be an actual shell command, not a perl subroutine. The error message comes from perl trying to execute the stringified reference to the sub, `CODE(0x67bc50)` in the shell.

To get the return value from the subroutine as the command, use `$cmd->()`. That might not do what I think you expect it to, though.

Comment: Why doesn't open3 support perl subrutine?

Comment: You can make it support it, if you call it properly. E.g. `$cmd->()`. Then I am guessing open3 uses the return value of the sub as the command.

Comment: Perhaps you are using the Wrong Tool for the job. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Run a subrutine in a sub process ,and get its output in the parent.

Comment: @new_perl: Why not just fix the subroutine to return the string instead of writing string to stdout? Anyway, you can always use fork-open if not.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the sub into its own script. Or you could use the special "`-`" command to fork without running `exec`.

```
my $pid = open3(*A, *B, *C, '-');
if (!$pid) {
   run();
   exit(0);
}
```

By the way,

```
my @outlines = <B>; 
my @errlines = <C>;
```

suffers from a race condition. I the child prints enough to STDERR to fill up the pipe, the two processes will deadlock. It's very hard to get this right, so I suggest you use a higher-level module such as IPC::Run.

Comment: Does the race condition exists if the special command `-` is not used?

Comment: How? IMO if `-` is not used, then `exec` will be called for child,so that it has no chance to run `my @outlines = <B>; 
my @errlines = <C>; `,how can there still be race condition?

Comment: @new_perl, The parent block reading B until the child exits. If the child blocks printing to STDERR, there's nothing to unblock it, since the parent will never read from C before the child exits.

Comment: @new_perl, It might use `select`.

Comment: Do you mean it makes uses of the `timeout` parameter of `select`? Can you provide an example of that?

Comment: @new_perl, No, to find out which pipe has data waiting to be read so that it can be emptied. Right now, you're just emptying B before the child exits. One needs to empty both B and C.